# Passing an argument to a controller with an initialize method

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I have a tableView in that specific controller which i want to initialize with the passed argument's values. 
The problem is, the initialize method is being executed before the controller sets The argument to a varaible.
Any suggestions would be great.

I am refering to the Location argument just to be clear.

**here is the call method for the controller:**

```
protected static void openReservationNewDialog(Location loc){
    try{
         FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();

            loader.setLocation(viewLogic.class.getResource("openNewReservations.fxml"));

            AnchorPane page = (AnchorPane) loader.load();
            Stage dialogStage = new Stage();
            dialogStage.setTitle("New Reservation");
            dialogStage.setResizable(false);
            Scene scene = new Scene(page);
            dialogStage.setScene(scene);
            openReservationNewDialogController controller=loader.getController();

                controller.setDialogStage(dialogStage);
                controller.setSelectedLocation(loc);
            dialogStage.showAndWait();

    } catch(Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**here is the relevant controller part:**

```
public class openReservationNewDialogController implements Initializable{

    @FXML
    private  TextField reservationId;
    /**Reservation's member*/
    @FXML
    private  ComboBox<String> member=new ComboBox<String>();
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> sMinutes= new ComboBox<String>(); 
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> eMinutes= new ComboBox<String>(); 
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> sHours= new ComboBox<String>();
    @FXML
    private ComboBox<String> eHours= new ComboBox<String>();
    private ArrayList<String> minutes=new ArrayList<>();
    private ArrayList<String> hours= new ArrayList<String>();
    @FXML
    /**Reservation's pick'n'drop locations (the same)*/
    private  Location loc;
    /**Reservation's start time*/
    @FXML
    private  DatePicker startTimeAndDate;
    /**Reservation's end time*/
    @FXML
    private DatePicker endTimeAndDate;
    private Stage dialogStage;
    @FXML
    private ObservableList<Reservation> loca=FXCollections.observableArrayList();
    @FXML
    private TableView<Reservation> table;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Reservation, String> reservationID;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Reservation, String> startTimeAndDateRes;
    @FXML
    private TableColumn<Reservation, String> endTimeAndDateREs;

    public void setSelectedLocation(Location selectedLocation){

        this.loc=selectedLocation;
    }

        @FXML
        private void handleCancel(){
            dialogStage.close();    
        }
        public void setDialogStage(Stage dialogStage) {
            this.dialogStage=dialogStage;

        }

        @Override
        public void initialize(URL location, ResourceBundle resources) {
             reservationId.addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_TYPED , TextFilters.numeric_Validation(4));

                for(Member mem : viewLogic.sData.getMembers().values()){
                    member.getItems().add(mem.getMemIdp().get());
                }
                //set combo boxes for time
                initializeMinutes();
                sMinutes.getItems().addAll(minutes);
                eMinutes.getItems().addAll(minutes);
                initializeHours();
                sHours.getItems().addAll(hours);
                eHours.getItems().addAll(hours);




                if(!loc.getReservations().isEmpty()){
                loca.addAll((viewLogic.sData.getLocations().get(loc.getIdP().get()).getReservations().values()));
                reservationID.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getReservationIdp());
                startTimeAndDateRes.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getStartTimeAndDateP());
                endTimeAndDateREs.setCellValueFactory(cellData -> cellData.getValue().getEndTimeAndDateP());
                table.setItems(loca);}

        }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instantiate the controller class in advance, then set it to FXMLLoader:

```
MyController mc = new MyController();
mc.setInitData(myData);
FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader();
loader.setController(mc);
...
loader.load();
```